# How do I blend the edges of an iframe into the background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe with no background that is layered on top of an image. I need it to appear as though the contents of the iframe fade away near the left and right edges.

In other words, the opacity of the iframe needs fade near the edges. Is this possible?

Comment: This might help: [Clipping and Masking in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) (Note: Does not seem to work very well in FF)

Comment: Is this close to what you're looking for? [codepen link](http://codepen.io/bonzo/pen/mEgdjq?editors=1100) I can change it more towards what you're looking for and submit it as an answer then.

Comment: thanks AlexG, I have it working now